# Moving StartActivityforResult to external class

Tags: android, oop

I am trying to tidy up my code so that I can easily reuse elements without having to duplicate work/ code.

I have a contactpicker and code to process the result in my application that I want to put into its own external class so I can reuse it in multiple areas.

I have got stuck on one issue- in order to call the StartActivityforResult, I need to pass the activity to the external class- however I am not sure how to do that?

Here is the class I am using as the external contact picker:

```
    public class ContactFinder {

    private static final int CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT = 1001;
    private Activity atv;
    public ContactFinder(Activity atv) {
        this.atv=atv;
    }
public void startContactPicker()
{
    Intent contactPickerIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);
    //Shows CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT cannot be resolved to a variable
    atv.startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT);

}
}
```

so how would I call it from my main activity using the following:

```
ContactFinder cf=new ContactFinder(???));// how do I pass the activity to this external class

cf.startContactPicker();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass `this` as `Activity` in which you are creating this Object.

```
ContactFinder cf=new ContactFinder(this);
cf.startContactPicker();
```

Keep in mind to implement `onActivityResult()` in your `Activity` also, to handle the result given by the started `Activity`.

Better to have a basic `Activity` class to which will implement `onActivityResult()` for your `ContactFinder` and extend every `Activity` (in which you want to use `ContactFinder`) from basic `Actvitiy`

Comment: I actually implemented the result within the same external class and then created a getter to pull in the data into the current activity.  I can see why yours would work too.  Many thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

what you can do is pass context in you class constructor from activity. and save it. Later you can use that context to create dialogs and whatever you want from that activity.

```
class myclass {
    Context context;

    myclass(Context temp_context) {
       context = temp_context;
    }
}
```

From atcitivity you have to do like that:

```
myclass ob = new myclass(getApplicationContext() or this);
```

now you can use context in your class for any purpose same as activity.
Like if you want to startactivity then you can simply write.

```
context.StartActivity(intent);
```

hope it will help you..